# How to configure the Projection for particular method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using spring-boot-starter-parent 1.4.1.RELEASE. The REST resource will render the attribute as a URI to it’s corresponding associated resource. We need to return the associated object instead of URI.

Projection will do the associated objects instead of URI but I need to configure this for each class.

e.g

```
@Entity
public class Person {

  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String firstName, lastName;

  @ManyToOne
  private Address address;
  …
}
```

PersonRepository:

```
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    Person findByName(@Param("name") @RequestParam("name") String name);
    Person findById(@Param("id") @RequestParam("id") int id);
```

}

PersonRepository returns,

```
{
  "firstName" : "Frodo",
  "lastName" : "Baggins",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1"
    },
    "address" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1/address"
    }
  }
}
```

My Projection:

```
@Projection(name = "inlineAddress", types = { Person.class }) 
interface InlineAddress {

  String getFirstName();

  String getLastName();

  Address getAddress(); 
}
```

After adding projection, it returns..

```
{
  "firstName" : "Frodo",
  "lastName" : "Baggins",
  "address" : { 
    "street": "Bag End",
    "state": "The Shire",
    "country": "Middle Earth"
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1"
    },
    "address" : { 
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1/address"
    }
  }
}
```

I have 2 get call in my Person repository. But I need the expanded associated object in **findById** but not **findByName**.

How to configure this in Projection?

If I configure like the following, it returns the both methods But I need the association object in findById method only.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = Inlineaddress.class)
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    Person findByName(@Param("name") @RequestParam("name") String name);
    Person findById(@Param("id") @RequestParam("id") int id);
}
```

Then How to configure the **Projection** for particular method???

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data supports returning a Projection from a query method from the Hopper Release onwards:

https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/03/what-s-new-in-spring-data-hopper#projections-on-repository-query-methods

So it should simply be a case of returning the relevant Projection from your query method:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = Inlineaddress.class)
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    Person findByName(@Param("name") @RequestParam("name") String name);
    InlineAddress findById(@Param("id") @RequestParam("id") int id);
}
```